# What is the difference between DOMNodeInserted and DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

According to the DOM events in wiki found [in the wiki link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events),

`DOMNodeInserted`: Fires when a node has been added as a child of another node

`DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument`: Fires when a node is being inserted into a document

Now what is the real difference? Shouldn't both events be the same? If not when and where should be used?

The scenario where I am using the above mentioned DOM events is that, I have a set of pages and each page loads a nav.jsp file inside a div reserved for navigation. Now I want to highlight the current page's nav tab hence I give it a small background property after that DOM element ( nav DIV) is loaded.

Now for my problem:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) { 
      if(e.target.id=="navigate"){
      //...........
      }
 });
```

worked, but just curious what is the difference is between the two events specified in my question?

Comment: Be aware `MutationEvent`s are [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#glossary-deprecated) in favour of `MutationObserver`s. See the warning in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#legacy-mutationevent-events).

Comment: Also be aware that `MutationObserver` is flawed in a way that `MutationEvent`s are not, before shooting onself in the foot: https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/1111

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` event is similar to the `DOMNodeInserted` event, but it occurs when a node is inserted into the document.

For example, if a node is added to an element that is not a part of the document, the `DOMNodeInserted` event is fired but the `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` event is not. If the parent element of a node is inserted into the document, the `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` event is fired but the `DOMNodeInserted` event is not.

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghyga4v6/2/

Try removing the container when text node is still there and inserting it back in to see the different events triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation with a working fiddle example.

Answer (score 5):

Here're two articles you can read about

1. [DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljimhdto.php)
2. [DOMNodeInserted event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php)

For example, you can insert `Node` into [BOM](https://css-tricks.com/dom/) element for developing browser extension or manipulate the history.

i.e. the **BOM** consists of the objects navigator , history , screen , location and document which are children of window . In the document node is the DOM, the document object model, which represents the contents of the page. You can manipulate it using javascript.(From wiki)

Here's a snippet to help, if you want to continue to learn.

```
$(window).on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', function(){
  console.log('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument occurred');
});

$(window).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
  console.log('DOMNodeInserted occurred');
});
```

By the way, just for your information. [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is replacing [Mutation Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#legacy-mutationevent-events).

Comment: `MutationObserver`...  Good call on adding that even though it's an old question.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same because the first one should also fire when adding a new node to a node that is outside of the document (created and not yet appended, or previously removed from its parent).